TM transmission coefficent derivation
Please help, I have exams and I am not sure if my derivation for transmission coefficient for TM case is correct.


@Franc Thank you for your input. I got the drawing from my lecturer's notes. What way should i do it then. I would appreciate your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
